# Count how many times a specific mathematic equation is wrong, and display at the end

Tags: c#

Basically I've created a times table app. At the end of the app, I've been able to say how many times I got it wrong, and how many times I got it right.

However I want it to say:

You got:

6 x 4 wrong 6 times.

5 x 2 wrong 9 times.

etc...

Rather than you got 20 correct, and 8 wrong.

So I can see the specific multiplications I got wrong. I know where I need to add the code (under the else statement). But not sure how to go about this.

I thought the best solution would be storing all the wrongs as a string in an array, then counting identical strings and outputting a number. But I have no idea how to do this.

Here's my code:

```
namespace TimesTablesGame
{
class multiplication
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    int randomNumber;
    int randomNumberTables;
    int c = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int numberOfGos = 0;
    int minRangeTables;
    int maxRangeTables;
    int minRange;
    int maxRange;


    public multiplication()
    {
    start:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the lowest number range you would like to practice your times tables on: ");
        minRangeTables = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the higest number range you would like to practice your times tables on: ");
        maxRangeTables = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the number of times you would like play: ");
        numberOfGos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the minimum range you would like to multiply by: ");
        minRange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the maximum range you would like to multiply by: ");
        maxRange = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    repeat:
        Console.Clear();


        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfGos; i++)
        {


            randomNumberTables = rng.Next(minRangeTables, maxRangeTables + 1);
            randomNumber = rng.Next(minRange, maxRange + 1);



            Console.Write("\n\n{0}: {1} x {2} = ", i, randomNumberTables, randomNumber);

            if (randomNumberTables * randomNumber == int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Correct");
                c++;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong it is: " + randomNumberTables * randomNumber);

                w++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nYou were correct {0} times, and wrong {1} times.", c, w);

        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? Type y for Yes with new settings, r for repeat using last settings, and any other key to exit.");
        char again = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        if (again == 'y')
        {
            c = 0;
            w = 0;
            goto start;
        }
        else if (again == 'r')
        {
            c = 0;
            w = 0;
            goto repeat;
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: `goto`s already. We're in trouble.

Comment: So ah, it seems you are using the `goto` statement.  There's a time and a place for everything -- even `goto` -- but IMHO, this is not one of those.

Comment: Those goto statements work fine, I don't see why they're a problem. I'd rather have help with my question though, thank you.

Comment: Start by reading C# book. The easiest way is to create multi-dimensional array, such as int[,] wrongTable = new int[randomNumberTables+1, randomNumber+1]; and update it as you go, such as wrongTable[randomNumberTable, randomNumber]++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd keep track in a Dictionary....

Resisting the urge to re-write the GOTO stuff.....here's a relatively simple way to do it:

```
Dictionary<string, int> wrongs;

//Console questions...

//Begin looping logic

wrongs = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfGos; i++)
{
    randomNumberTables = rng.Next(minRangeTables, maxRangeTables + 1);
    randomNumber = rng.Next(minRange, maxRange + 1);

    string eq = String.Format("{0} x {1} = ", randomNumberTables, randomNumber);

    Console.Write("{0}: " + eq, i);

    if (randomNumberTables * randomNumber == int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct");
        c++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong it is: " + randomNumberTables * randomNumber);

        if (wrongs.Any(x => x.Key == eq))
        {
            wrongs[eq]++;
        }
        else
        {
            wrongs.Add(eq, 1);
        }

        w++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("\nYou were correct {0} times, and wrong {1} times.", c, w);

Console.WriteLine("\n\nYou got:");
foreach (var item in wrongs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} wrong {1} times", item.Key, item.Value);
}

//Your logic to repeat/restart
```

Also....note that this does not count "2 x 4" and "4 x 2" as the same equation....

Also also....You can easily do this without using GOTO....please consider it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I've added the new code, and am sudying. However the if and else statement doesn't seem to work for me. If I put in an incorrect value, I get the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: Scrap that, I copy and pasted your entire code, and it seems to be working now. Thanks for the reply man, you actually helped me out a lot. Now I will have to go and study it. You were very helpful, other people no so much.